# CMake: cannot find source file on add_library of sibling library

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake project with the following directory structure:

- CMakeLists.txt
- A/CMakeLists.txt
- B/CMakeLists.txt

*A* and *B* both describe shared libraries, and **B** depends upon **A**.

Calling `cmake` on the entire project gives no problems. Neither does building *A*, but building *B* tells me it misses symbols from *A*. This makes sense, and so I solved that by adding `target_link_libraries(B A)` to B/CMakeLists.txt.

However, when I call `cmake` now, I get errors about *B/CMakeLists.txt* not being able to find source files from *A*. Apparently, to solve this, I should add `target_include_directories(A PUBLIC .)` to *A/CMakeLists.txt*, but that does not work. What am I missing here?

---

For completion's sake, here's the dumbed-down CMake files:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5.1)

project(main C CXX)

add_subdirectory(A)
add_subdirectory(B)
```

A/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5.1)

add_library(A SHARED "")

target_include_directories(A PUBLIC .)
target_sources(A PUBLIC ...)
```

B/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5.1)

add_library(B SHARED "")
target_link_libraries(B A)
target_sources(B PUBLIC ...)
```

---

The error I get is the following

> CMake Error at B/CMakeLists.txt:3 (add_library):
>     Cannot find source file:
>
> Access.hpp
>
> Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx

---

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.kaizou.org/2014/11/typical-cmake-project/), explaining about `target_link_libraries` and `target_include_directories`.

Comment: In `add_library()` you specify source files (*c, *.cpp) to build library from. What is `Access.hpp` header is doing there?

Comment: It's there because I'd like to see the headers turn up in the generated XCode and CodeBlocks projects. If I leave the headers out, the same error throws up the first .cpp file (`BinPackingSpace.cpp`).

Comment: It's in the same directory as that `B/CMakeLists.txt` file?

Comment: Good question, and no: That's a file from A. The error throws for B/CMakeLists.txt, but it's about a source file from A it says it can't find.

Comment: Then don't do that. Don't compile files from A into the B library.

Comment: I don't. No file from A is mentioned in B. As soon as I add the line `target_link_libraries(B A)` the errors throw up. I add it to inform CMake about B depending on A. As far as I know that's the way to do this, but I am new to CMake and frankly, the documentation isn't always that helpful. I'll edit and add the tutorial I'm following for this reasoning here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `target_sources()`. Add source files to the `add_library()` command.

Or use `target_sources()` with `PRIVATE`.

Comment: Why does it need to be `PRIVATE`?

Comment: @voddan, I think that when sources are private the other target won't need them.

Comment: it doesn't use them anyways. How `PRIVATE` affects the way it looks for the files? Or is it a misleading error message?

Comment: @voddan, maybe some generators use `INTERFACE_SOURCES`, maybe CMake verifies that `INTERFACE_SOURCES` is filled correctly even when the current generators doesn't use it. Adding the sources like `PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Access.hpp` will probably fix it too.

Comment: The problem is that full path indeed fixes it. WTF?

Comment: @voddan, `target_sources()` assigns a value (which is array of strings) to the variables (`SOURCES`, `INTERFACE_SOURCES`) of this target. It doesn't memorize at the directory where the `CMakeLists.txt` or these files are located. The `add_library(B ...)` finds the files because here the current directory (B) actually matters. The `add_library(A ...)` and `target_link_libraries(A ...)` don't find the files because the current directory is A.